# asp.net mvc Dropdownlist, showing dropdownlist, but no items in it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have this:

```
    FaqCategorieService faqCategorieService;

    public FAQController(FaqCategorieService faqCategorieService)
    {
        this.faqCategorieService = faqCategorieService;
    }

    // GET: FAQ
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(FaqOverviewModel model)
    {
        var categories = faqCategorieService.GetAll().OrderBy(x => x.Naam)
            .Select(a => new FaqOverviewModel()
            {
                Id = a.Id,
                Naam = a.Naam
            }).ToList();

        foreach (var categorie in categories)
        {
            categorie.Naam = categorie.Naam + " (" + categorie.Id.ToString() + ")";
        }

        categories.Insert(0, new FaqOverviewModel() { Id = -1, Naam = "Maak een keuze..." });

        //var cats = faqCategorieService.GetAll().ToList();


        return View(model);
        //  return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
    }
```

**ModelView:**

```
public class FaqOverviewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EmailBericht { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }

    public FaqOverviewModel()
    {

        Categorie = new List<FaqCategorie>();
    }

    public FaqOverviewModel(IEnumerable<FaqCategorie> categories)
    {
        this.Categorie = categories;
    }   

    #region FAQCategorie
    private readonly IEnumerable<FaqCategorie> Categorie;

    public int? SelectedCategoriedFaqId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FAQCategorieItems
    {

        get
        {
            return new SelectList(Categorie, "Id", "Naam");
        }

    }
    #endregion

    #region subcategorie

    #endregion
}
```

**View:**

### Support

```
<p>
    <span class="fixedLabelWidth">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedCategoriedFaqId, "Categorie:")</span>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCategoriedFaqId, Model.FAQCategorieItems)

</p>   

<p>
    <span class="fixedLabelWidth">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailBericht, "Bericht:")</span>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.EmailBericht)
</p>
```

I see the dropdownlist, But there are now items in it.

Model.FAQCategorieItems: `count = 0`. But if I put in a breakpoint in the controller I see all the items from the database.

Thank you.

Comment: you are returning  return View(model);.. isn't it be like return View(categories);

Comment: Hi Neel but then I get this error:

Comment: Hi Neel,  this error:Server Error in '/Medicijnverstrekking' Application.

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Multitask.Regenboog.Medicijnverstrekking.WebApplication.ViewModels.FAQ.FaqOverviewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Multitask.Regenboog.Medicijnverstrekking.WebApplication.ViewModels.FAQ.FaqOverviewModel'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: can you show the line where you bind your model in view?

Comment: That is here:<p>
        <span class="fixedLabelWidth">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedCategoriedFaqId, "Categorie:")</span>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCategoriedFaqId, Model.FAQCategorieItems)
                        
    </p> but in controller I see the items, but in the View it shows: count 0:Model.FAQCategorieItems

Comment: And above in the view page I have it like this:@using Multitask.Regenboog.Medicijnverstrekking.Domain
@model Multitask.Regenboog.Medicijnverstrekking.WebApplication.ViewModels.FAQ.FaqOverviewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Support</h2>

Comment: I realy dont know what is wrong

Comment: try to take list of viewmodel in view

Comment: I'v done it like this:// GET: FAQ
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(/*FaqOverviewModel model*/)
        {
            var categories = faqCategorieService.GetAll().OrderBy(x => x.Naam);
            //var subCategorie = faqCategorieSubService.GetById().;

            FaqOverviewModel model = new FaqOverviewModel(categories);
            return View(model);
            
        }

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is adding your items in a list. but the items in the list has to be mapped to the property of the model.
Add line

```
model= new FaqOverviewModel(categories);
```

before

```
return View(model);
```

Comment: can u try with removing readonly and then changing IEnumerable to List.